# Javascript confirm()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submit button something like this:

```
<button class="btn " type="submit" form="test" name="test" value="test" onClick="return onSave()">Save</button>
```

I have this `javascript` code in `onSave()` function

```
function onSave(){
             var dropdownCounter = 0;
             var textareaCounter = 0;

             $('tr[class="test"]').each(function(){
                 var textarea =  $(this).find('textarea');
                 var dropdown = $(this).find('select');

                 dropdown.filter(function(){
                     if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0 || $(this).val() == 'nothing_selected'){
                         dropdownCounter++;
                     }
                 });
                 textarea.filter(function(){
                     if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
                         textareaCounter++;
                     }
                 });
             });
             if( ( dropdownCounter + textareaCounter ) % 5 != 0) {
                 confirm("test"); // this one is not working
                     return false;
             }
             return true;
         }
```

The button should fail if it meets the condition in the `if statement` but I also need to have a prompt there, but it seems that `return method()` on the `onClick` doesn't trigger the `confirm()`. What approach should i do to fix this?

**Update:**

```
<c:forEach var="test" value="${test}">
<table>
    <tr class='test'>
        <td><textarea class="no-resize" id="comments"></textarea></td>
        <td><select class="select"> ... </select> </td>
        <td><textarea class="no-resize" id="reason"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="no-resize" id="description"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</c:forEach>
```

The structure of the table

Comment: Can you post the rest of your HTML code? From the JS it looks like you have a table and some dropdowns that it would be helpful to see.

Comment: Or directly create a jsFiddle?

Comment: You're using jQuery, so create a proper event handler that prevents the default action of the button, which looks like it submits a form.

Comment: If you're just using `confirm` for an informational alert, you should use `alert` instead of `confirm` (since confirm presents two options and alert just one)

Comment: @DonovanCharpin I can't post the whole table because it is iterated by EL

Comment: @adeneo sorry for being slow but what do you mean?

Comment: @Jim i need to use confirm because i will do something if the user clicked the positive option

Comment: Have you considered that (dropdownCounter + textareaCounter)%5 is false when the code above is executed ^^?

Comment: @jsmorph I'm absolutely sure that the condition is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use else part of the if condition

```
 if( ( dropdownCounter + textareaCounter ) % 5 != 0) {
             confirm("test"); // this one is not working
                 return false;
         }else{
         return true;
}
```

Comment: Awesome it works. But can you tell me the reason why it isn't working without an else?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` handler in your HTML does not need a `return` value.

```
<button class="btn " type="submit" form="test" name="test" value="test" onClick="onSave()">Save</button>
```